# How to refer to table SCHEMA using TSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, schema

I am using AdventureWorksLT and each of the tables has the SalesLT Schema;
each time I have to do a query I need to make a reference to the SalesLT Schema:

`SELECT * FROM SalesLT.Address`

This makes querying very extensive; is there a way to refer to the SalesLT Schema, without having to write it in every query e.g.

`SELECT * FROM Address`

Comment: I would hardly call schema-qualifying object names extensive work. I suggest you just get used to it since the schema name is part of object names and will improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to give the schema name you can set the default schema for a user -

**To Set the default Schema**

```
ALTER USER [yourUser] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = [YourSchema];
```

**To See the Schema -**

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME()
```

Comment: From [`Alter User`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): "The value of DEFAULT_SCHEMA is ignored if the user is a member of the **sysadmin** fixed server role. All members of the **sysadmin** fixed server role have a default schema of `dbo`."

Answer (score 0):

Use `ALTER SCHEMA` to define the default schema. This change is permanent until you run this command again:

```
ALTER USER <user> WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = <my-schema>
```

As far as I know, there's no way of altering the default schema just for the session. It's a permanent change.